# OAuth2 with intridea ruby gem

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, foursquare

I have the following code:

```
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000')
response = token.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins', {:mode => :query})
```

The problem is that no matter what :mode I specify I always get a Bearer token in Authorization header. The code in question is a private set_token which always depends on the default :mode which is always :header.

Am I using it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what your question is? What do you mean by bearer token?

Comment: See section 7.0 of latest (draft 20) OAuth2 RFC: "Authorization: Bearer 7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a problem how the oauth2 gem passes variabels inside the objects so mode and param_name seems to be lost on the way. A solution to the problem would be to create a new AccessToken object with the correct parameters instead of using the shorthand. This example is tested against Foursquares api and it works.

```
require "oauth2"

client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  "CLIENT_ID",
  "CLIENT_SECRET", 
  :authorize_url => "/oauth2/authorize", 
  :token_url => "/oauth2/access_token", 
  :site => "https://foursquare.com/"
)

puts client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => "http://localhost:4000")

code = gets.chomp

token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:4000")

token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, token.token, {
  :mode => :query,
  :param_name => "oauth_token",
})

response = token.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins')

puts response.body
```

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I have a valid access token and the problem is in the way it is used in the request to get data from the API itself. I tried your example and didn't see a difference. Have you tried running it against foursquare?

Comment: The default name of the access token param used in the gem is `bearer_token`. But foursquare does not use that name it uses `oauth_token` instead. So pass in `param_name` into the request. I changed the example.

Comment: It seems that the oauth2 client don't pass on variables correct so you need to create  a new access token object to bypass this. I made some code and tested it against foursquares api and it works. You can find the code at https://gist.github.com/4aa03f41f158b7d52210

Comment: That what was my suspicion. Your answer is correct. I'll file a bug with the intridea team as well.

Comment: The bug is now [fixed](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/commit/7ece6288905d51d4eebc5f87e7fafdb4b197fa58)