# Yahoo API with Ruby on Rails and OAUTH2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I have an RoR site that gets data from stock exchanges and I am using Yahoo's finance table via the Yahoo API. I need authorization to gain full access to YQL, which requires that I use Oauth2.  I need help getting OAuth access to Yahoo.

This is what I have tried:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(oauth_consumer_key,oauth_consumer_secret, {
        access_token_path:   '/oauth/v2/get_token',
        authorize_path:      '/oauth/v2/request_auth',
        authorize_url:       'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth',
        request_token_path:  '/oauth/v2/get_request_token',
        site:                'https://api.login.yahoo.com'
    })
puts client.auth_code.authorize_url( redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000")
code = gets.chomp
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000")
```

I don't know which "code" I must use. Authorize_url returns me this [URL](https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?response_type=code&client_id=dj0yJmk9YTlQOVhqeURmaTVYJmQ9WVdrOVZtUlVWMnBoTm5FbWNHbzlNVE14TWpBeU5qTTJNZy0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD0wYg--), but it is unclear what the "code". I was inspired by this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236193/oauth2-with-intridea-ruby-gem).

Comment: OAuth works in two steps: 1) you make a call like the one above passing your key and secret, which should get you to place where you can 2) get an authorization token.  The authorization token is then used in subsequent requests for content.  The example you pointed to and use makes some assumptions.  I am sure there are good examples of how to use OAuth with Yahoo's API -- while the protocol is the same, there are a number of different approaches -- you need to understand which one Yahoo uses.

Comment: Also, you don't mention if you're using a gem, and if so, which one.

Comment: I use "oauth2" gem. I tried this tutorial: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-requesttoken.html, but I don't understand "oauth_signature" so google say me OAUTH is better solution.

Comment: Check here for some examples of how to use OAuth from ruby: http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/#oauth

Comment: thank you, but it's not good for me, https://gist.github.com/383159 this is without OAUTH2 gem.

Comment: I think it's up to you from here, then.  The page I linked has several good examples, and Google should provide even more.

Comment: Thank you, but you think I have problem in my code or I must get from yahoo "code" to allow API (http://d.pr/i/qj3i)?

Comment: So ... isn't the "code" returned by `gets.chomp` the one you need to enter on the form?

Comment: "gets.chomp" reads from the keyboard so I must have the "code" but I don't have it.

Comment: I based on the gist's code that quatermain provided above and create a detailed description here (It cost me 5 days to authenticate with yahoo and make a success call to yahoo API): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SdGSfakQM3ZuiqJK7keXhOfh6310-z_h0THl1_Jswxk/pub

Comment: @datnt add it as answer, please.

Answer (score 4):

Don't ask me why but Yahoo has made it very hard to find their OAuth 2.0 documention. [I found it, though](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/index.html)!

Also, pretty "awesome" that you get a `refresh_token` without needing to explicitly ask the user for "offline" permissions. In my opinion, this is a security concern for Yahoo. Both Google and Microsoft require explicit "offline" access.

```
require 'oauth2'

OAuth2::Client.new(Rails.application.secrets.yahoo_consumer_id, Rails.application.secrets.yahoo_consumer_secret, site: 'https://api.login.yahoo.com', authorize_url: '/oauth2/request_auth', token_url: '/oauth2/get_token')
client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: redirect_uri, headers: { "Authorization" => basic_authorization })
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: redirect_uri)

# Later
token.refresh!
```

Comment: You should also find [my pull request](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/pull/192) to fix the need for authorization headers in the OAuth2 gem API.

Comment: did this line work? token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: redirect_uri). mine is throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply, so the reason I wanted to get the token is because I wanted to access my yahoo contacts.

Comment: @maletor 's PR #192 to fix the need for authorization headers was redone and merged in https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2/pull/280.  It has been part of the last couple releases.  Yet another new release of the gem is coming out soon.

Answer (score 0):

As per quatermain's request, I post my solution as answer here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SdGSfakQM3ZuiqJK7keXhOfh6310-z_h0THl1_Jswxk/pub

P/S: There is some mistype I made within the document, as below:

- The sentence: "I don't this this URL affect to authentication process..." --> shoud be "I don't think this URL affect to authentication process..."
- The word "and ready through" --> should be "and read through"