# Using omnicontacts gem to get yahoo contacts in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, sinatra, contacts, yahoo-api, import-contacts

I am trying to import yahoo contacts using [omnicontacts gem on github](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts). But the documentation shows only how to use in Ruby on Rails. I want to use Sinatra or simply a ruby script.

**Here is the gem and the documentation: [omnicontacts gem on github](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts).**
I have been researching online the past few hours any resources but I am not getting any. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The example shows the gem being used as a middleware; so suggesting a way to use middleware with Sinatra:

Contents of `config.ru`:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'omnicontacts'

use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, "client_id", "client_secret", {:redirect_path => "/oauth2callback", :ssl_ca_file => "/etc/ssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt"}
  importer :yahoo, "consumer_id", "consumer_secret", {:callback_path => '/callback'}
  importer :hotmail, "client_id", "client_secret"
  importer :facebook, "client_id", "client_secret"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a web-server, so probably you want to use [Authorization Flow for Web Servers](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#authorization-code-flow-for-server-side-apps): take a look to understand the flow.

**In few words**: you need to get provide a link to user consent, get a code from Yahoo, then request the OAuth2 token.

You can find a working code for Sinatra + OmniAuth [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Sinatra-Example) and [here](http://blog.dennis-schneider.com/2013/10/03/sinatra-omniauth-provider-app.html).

Yahoo has several Ruby examples here: https://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/

You can consider, too, use importer services like [CloudSponge.com](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/ruby), which provides Ruby APIs for several contact sources (like Yahoo, Gmail, Linkedin, Outlook/Hotmail, AOL, Facebook, etc).

**Disclaimer**: I work for CloudSponge.

Comment: Hello Rael, I don't wan to use importer services.could you suggest better gems to use with yahoo?

Comment: @ben Both examples I've pasted are using [OAuth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) instead of Omnicontacts. You can check [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705080/yahoo-api-with-ruby-on-rails-and-oauth2) too.