# error fetching Oauth2 token from yahoo: OAuth2::Error invalid_request: {"error":"invalid_request"}

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra, yahoo, yahoo-api

I have a simple problem that is getting me stuck. I have been following this yahoo documentation [Yahoo OAuth 2.0 Guide](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#yahoo-oauth-2-0-guide) . I have been able to generate authorization URL and even get the authorization code.(that is upto [Step 3](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#authorization-code-flow-for-server-side-apps-step-3-user-redirected-for-access-authorization)).

But now I am stuck in step 4:  [Exchange authorization code for Access Token](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#authorization-code-flow-for-server-side-apps-step-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token). I am also using this StackOverflow question [Yahoo API with Ruby on Rails and OAUTH2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705080/yahoo-api-with-ruby-on-rails-and-oauth2). This is my code(I'm using sinatra):

```
get '/yahoo/contacts/oauth2callback' do
  client = OAuth2::Client.new($consumer_id, $consumer_secret, site: $yahoo_base_url, authorize_url: '/oauth2/request_auth', token_url: '/oauth2/get_token')
  code = params[:code] if params[:code]
  puts "Code: #{code}"
  # token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: $yahoo_redirect_url, headers: { "Authorization" => Basic })
  token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: $yahoo_redirect_url)
  puts "THIS IS THE NEW TOKEN NOW: #{token}"
end
```

the variable used include:

```
# for yahoo application
$consumer_id = "dj0yJmk9Q1RKU2x2NTY3WWVxJmQ9WVdrOU1YWnRUV2cyTXpBbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1fth--"
$consumer_secret = "my_secret"
$yahoo_redirect_url = "http://localhost:4567/yahoo/contacts/oauth2callback"
```

What What is causing the error? Because the error source is this line.

```
 token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: $yahoo_redirect_url)
```

what i'm I doing wrong?

**Update:** I had written the error at the title, and it seems many people can't see it.
the error is

```
 OAuth2::Error invalid_request: {“error”:“invalid_request”}
file: client.rb location: request line: 113
```

the returned url is looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4567/yahoo/contacts/oauth2callback?code=bck5tkm.
```

Where the code being taken is bck5tkm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use the intridea OAuth 2.0 client (https://github.com/intridea/oauth2), you may be bumping in to a bug:

```
https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/pull/192
```

meaning that Yahoo refuses to permit client credentials in the request body. The pull request has not been merged yet so you'd need to apply that to your own code (or find another gem that works).

Comment: Yahoo works with OAuth 2.0 but not with this specific client implementation; the client *should* send the credentials in a header and not in the body (but perhaps Yahoo should not refuse that, as it is a bit strict to interpret "not recommended" this way); you may be able to fix the client for your purposes

Comment: Thank you @Hans for understanding my question. If I may ask, what is the correct way of getting the token in yahoo?. I have done the same as with google and also as Oauth2 says(https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) but still it is not working. Could you help me with that please? From the guide(https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#authorization-code-flow-for-server-side-apps-step-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token) I am not understanding clearly.

Comment: use HTTP basic authentication with consumer key/secret and don't POST key/secret in the body; this is a valid `curl` command getting an access token from Yahoo using OAuth 2.0: `curl -u "<consumer_key>:<consumer_secret>" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>" https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token`

Comment: @Hi, Hans Z, still got the error after using your curl solution. I see that I use redirect_uri different, as I use "oob" to get the code as example in the link(https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/) in step 2, so I also use "oob" as the redirect_url value in the curl cmd. Do you know is it possible to  use "oob" to finish the authentication? As I plan to run local script to get/update the data, so no redirect_uri is needed. Thanks

Comment: Tried php, curl cmd, finally, got the script work in python as discussed in topic here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817089/retrieve-access-token-for-yahoo-api-using-oauth-2-0-and-python-requests/31680234#31680234), hope this helps others. When "oob" is used  as redirect_uri, then you need to select a "Installed Application " when create the yahoo app, and leave the redirect_uri empty. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an expired or already used code(can be used just once). Or you have supplied not valid credentials in the HTTP Basic Authorization header on the POST request.

Comment: I am using this guide to implement. check section 4, it is where I am having a problem (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#authorization-code-flow-for-server-side-apps-step-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token)